# Read a actual physical block

Tags: linux-kernel, device-mapper

I have LBN->PBN map.
LBN - Logical Block Number.
PBN - Physical Block Number.

I can get each (LBN, PBN) entry from the above map.
Is there any API that I can use to read the data from the actual block device using this PBN. I am currently working in the linux kernel code /drivers/md.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look inside. I also grep thru sources and found a lot of accessor functions relative to fs. 
[The Linux Kernel API](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/)